# Double Foreach Array

Tags: php

I've two arrays:

```
array product_item('1','22','35');
array product_subitems(22 => array('35'=>'1','42'=>'15'), 35 => array('60'=>'10','69'=>'20'))
```

How do I to get the array product_subitems' value based on my array product_items?

I tried something like:

```
foreach($product_keys as $p_key) {
   foreach($product_items as $item_key) {
      echo product_keys[$p_key][$item_key];
   } 
}
```

But It's  a very poor code and doesn't work.

I just want to get the array keys and values from the second array based on the keys of my first array.

Comment: You mean you want to get the value from the second array with a key corresponding to a value from the first array, repeating for each value in the first?

Comment: `foreach($product_items as $i) { if(isset($product_subitems[$i])) { print_r($product_subitems[$i]); } }` ?

Comment: Yes, Nathan. Darren, I need to get the values in a loop, I'm using it in a shopping cart...

Comment: How do you mean in a loop @vinoli ?

Comment: Passing by each key of second array.. Using "for", "foreach" or "while" statements.

Comment: can you add a sample output that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is the keys in the sub array items right?

So, based off that, you'd want something like this:

```
foreach($product_items as $i) {
    if(isset($product_subitems[$i])) {
        foreach($product_subitems as $item) {
             foreach($item as $key => $value) {
                 echo "{$key} = {$value} \n";
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/292080)

---

If you don't care about the `product_subitems`s' keys, then you could use this to get the values:

```
foreach($product_items as $i) {
    if(isset($product_subitems[$i])) {
        $values = array_values($product_subitems[$i]);
        print_r($values);
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/292084)

Comment: Darren It worked perfectly, but I've a doubt, Is this method appropriated? Otherwise, what the correct way to do it? Thank you for sharing your knowledgment.

Comment: See update @vinoli, if you're interested in just the values of the sub arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the first and use each value to retrieve the correct array from the second. Something like this:

```
foreach ($product_item as $pi){
    print_r($product_subitems[$pi]);
}
```

Demo 1: http://codepad.org/LDZjHjQH

You can modify this however you need. For instance, you might want something like this:

```
foreach ($product_item as $pi){
    echo "Product item " . $pi . ": ";
    if (isset($product_subitems[$pi])) {
        foreach ($product_subitems[$pi] as $spi) {
            echo $spi . " ";
        }
    }    
}
```

Demo 2: http://codepad.org/eTe2ga3d

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_item = array('1','22','35');   
$product_subitems = array(22 => array('35'=>'1','42'=>'15'), 35 => array('60'=>'10','69'=>'20'));

foreach($product_item as $item)
   if(isset($product_subitems[$item]))
      print_r($product_subitems[$item]);
```